# Extract last numbers of sequences in a vector in R

Tags: r

This my vector:

```
myvector<-c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 142L, 143L, 149L, 150L)
```

As you can see there some sequences inside this vector:

```
Seq1: 1,2
Seq2: 4,5,6,7,8
Seq3: 10
Seq4: 12
Seq5: 142,143
Seq6: 149,150
```

Im trying to implement a code that identifies this sequences and extract the last onee. The result should be:

```
output<- c(2L, 8L,10L,12L, 143L, 150L)
```

I have other vectors bigger ones. But if I am able to do this with this vector I will be able to do with the others.

I tried to use `diff` but the last element is deleted.

Any help guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a grouping vector with `diff` and `cumsum`, use that in `tapply` to extract the last element

```
unname(tapply(myvector, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(myvector) != 1)), 
      FUN = tail, 1))
#[1]   2   8  10  12 143 150
```

Or another simple option is

```
by(myvector, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(myvector) != 1)), FUN = tail, 1)
```

---

Or an option is `split` into a `list`, extract the last element by looping through the `list`

```
lst1 <- split(myvector, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(myvector) != 1)),)
unname(sapply(lst1, tail, 1))
#[1] 2   8  10  12 143 150
```

---

Or create a grouping column in a data.frame/tibble and then do a regular `slice/filter`

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(val = myvector, grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(val) != 1))) %>% 
      group_by(grp) %>%          
      slice(n()) %>% 
      pull(val)
#[1]   2   8  10  12 143 150
```

Comment: @Laura That was actually my iniitial answer but then I was also intrigued by your expected output

Comment: @akrun Would you please explain this: `cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(myvector) != 1))`

Comment: @MAPK `diff` returns the difference of adjacent elements, but `diff` length is always one less than the actual length of the vector.  then, create a lgoical condition by checking whether thee length is not equal to 1 (that is where we find the breaks in the sequence), concatenate with a boolean (TRUE at the beginning to make the lengths same), and then do the cumulative sum.  Wherever theeree is TRUE, it adds 1, creating blocks or groups for to do the split

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution just with subsetting

```
myvector<-c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 142L, 143L, 149L, 150L)

myvector[which(diff(myvector) == 1)[!diff(which(diff(myvector, lag=1) == 1) + 1) == 1] + 1]
```

### Explanation

1. Identify sequences

`which(diff(myvector) == 1)`

> [1]  1  3  4  5  6 10 12

2. Identify ends of sequences

`!diff(which(diff(myvector, lag=1) == 1) + 1) == 1`

notice that this is a subset of the sequence vector

> [1]  1  6 10 12

3. Fix the index

`+1`

> [1]  2  7 11 13

These are the indices for the last elements of sequences! :)

### Optimization

Save subsetting operation done twice

```
seqs <- which(diff(myvector) == 1)
myvector[seqs[!diff(seqs + 1) == 1] + 1]

microbenchmark::microbenchmark({seqs <- which(diff(myvector) == 1)
+ myvector[seqs[!diff(seqs + 1) == 1] + 1]})
Unit: microseconds
                                                                                    expr
 {     seqs <- which(diff(myvector) == 1)     myvector[seqs[!diff(seqs + 1) == 1] + 1] }

   min      lq    mean median      uq    max neval
11.773 12.3345 13.2772 12.473 12.7435 68.969   100

microbenchmark::microbenchmark({myvector[which(diff(myvector) == 1)[!diff(which(diff(myvector, lag=1) == 1) + 1) == 1] + 1]})
Unit: microseconds
                                                                                                           expr
 {     myvector[which(diff(myvector) == 1)[!diff(which(diff(myvector,          lag = 1) == 1) + 1) == 1] + 1] }
    min     lq     mean  median     uq    max neval
 17.721 18.295 19.44263 18.5855 18.926 82.875   100
```

### Solution including single values

Even simpler since we do not have to take care of whether a value is part of a sequence or not. We subset by whether the next value breaks the "sequence". The final value is included in any case. Either it ends a sequence or it is a single value but we know there is not another incremental integer.

```
myvector<-c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 142L, 143L, 149L, 150L)
# Test with different vector
myvector2<-c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 142L, 143L, 148L, 150L)

lastSeq <- function(vector){
   return(vector[c(which(diff(vector) != 1), length(vector))] )
}
lastSeq(myvector)
lastSeq(myvector2)
```

Comment: many many thanks. But I did a mistake in my question. Could check again? I am trully sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think is the simplest solution so far -

```
x <- c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 142L, 143L, 149L, 150L)

d <- c(NA, diff(x))

ind <- d == 1 & c(d[-1], Inf) > 1

x[ind]

[1]   2   8 143 150
```

Explanation -

```
x
 [1]   1   2   4   5   6   7   8  10  12 142 143 149 150

c(NA, diff(x))
 [1]  NA   1   2   1   1   1   1   2   2 130   1   6   1

# looking at above we need values where every 1 is followed by value > 1
# and that's achieved by below condition -
ind <- d == 1 & c(d[-1], Inf) > 1
```

---

Solution to updated problem using `rle` from base R -

```
rl <- rle(min(x):max(x) %in% x)

ind <- with(
  rl,
  sequence(lengths[values]) == rep(lengths[values], lengths[values])
)

x[ind]
# [1]   2   8  10  12 143 150
```